# Can't see camera's 'passepartout' / overlay around the camera's view

Tags: camera

I have 'passepartout' selected in the Camera tab.

I have "Lock Camera to View" deselected in View (in the "N" tools section).

Yet I don't get a passepartout in Camera Perspective.

What am I doing wrong?[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you made sure it's not just offscreen by zooming out with the scroll wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Leander, I discovered it was offscreen.  I used to scroll wheel to scroll out (way, way out), and there it was.

Answer (score -1):

**Follow these steps for solution.**

[image]